# Return object with empty state (NULL) in C++ without returning a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

In **DOM** (Document Object Model) specification, interface Node has a method:

```
Node GetChild();
```

It states that if **Node** has no child then a return value is **NULL**.
What is the right way to implement this approach in **C++** without returning a pointer to a child Node. (Better to prevent from memory leaks)

Suggestion:

Have an attribute

```
bool is_null_;
```

and overload *operator bool()* to return this value.

```
Node child = node.GetChild();
if (child) { ... }
```

Comment: Return a smart pointer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Waiting a bit now, but the Library Fundamentals TS will be providing [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional).

Elsewise if you can use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which has similar semantics.

You can use it like:

```
using std::experimental::optional;

optional<Node> GetChild();

auto child = node.GetChild();
if (child) {
  const Node& childNode = child.value();
} else {
  std::cerr << "parent had no child" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `const Node& childNode = *child;` is the way the cool kids do it.

Comment: `const Node& childNode = *child;` You have to take make sure not to release child. And passing around this reference in other classes methods might be a problem. I prefer std::shared_pointer<Node>

Answer (score 3):

Such thing as `boost::optional` will help you: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html